# Svg clipPath to clip a div doesn't work in Safari when i duplicate it

Tags: html, css, svg, safari, clip-path

I have created a clip path that I reuse on multiple divs in the page. I use the property clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" to make it apply to each div based on its position.
 It works great in Chrome and Firefox. When I tried it in safari it only works based on the first div. Meaning that it works well the first time than when i call it again the boudingbox is still based on the first Div. I realized this when i gave a negative margin to the second div until it overlaped with the first one partial then I could see it.

Here is an example of the issue:

```css
.bar {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  z-index: 100;
  display: block;
  clip-path: url(#clipping);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipping);
}
```

```html
<svg style="background: blue; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipping" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M0.501,0.971c-0.014,0-0.027-0.003-0.04-0.011l-0.34-0.194c-0.024-0.014-0.04-0.041-0.04-0.069L0.081,0.306
 c0-0.028,0.015-0.055,0.04-0.069L0.458,0.04c0.013-0.007,0.026-0.011,0.04-0.011s0.027,0.003,0.04,0.011l0.339,0.194
 c0.025,0.014,0.041,0.041,0.041,0.069l0.001,0.391c0,0.028-0.015,0.055-0.04,0.069L0.542,0.96C0.529,0.968,0.515,0.971,0.501,0.971z
 " />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="bar" style="background: blue;">
  <div class="block">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bar" style="background: green;">
  <div class="block">
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/appteamio/pen/WbdRgx

I'm I doing something wrong or is it a Safari issue.If sois there any work aroung.
thanks

Comment: You might try using `-webkit-transform:translateZ(1px)` to force hardware acceleration

Comment: As @ZachSaucier mentioned, using `-webkit-transform:translateZ(1px)` or (-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0)` to force hardware acceleration on the div with the `clip-path` applied seemed to fix the issue in Safari; however it *completely* screws up in Chrome on both PC & Mac. Since they're both Webkit-based, I'm now stuck. Did you ever solve this across the board?

Comment: ...to answer my own comment (and question): I used a Chrome >28-specific `@supports` query to remove the `transform3d` - details here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31079763/988246

Comment: Over 6 years later, on the very latest version of Safari, this bug apparently still exists; I just ran into it. Sure enough, adding `transform: translateZ(0px)` on the parent of the thing with the clip path solved it for me. Who knew Safari would be the new IE.