# Clip path from svg on multiple images does not work in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg, safari

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28468314/1471485) in order to figure out how to clip multiple blocks with svg clip path in Safari. The soultion pointed out in the comments ( setting `-webkit-transform:translateZ(1)` on the element that needs clipping works. I am however not able to do a clipping if I have images instead of regular `div` blocks. I have outlined a new code snipped based on the original one from the linked question.

If you try to run the snippet in Chrome, and then in Safari, you will find that only one kitten is displayed in Safari, but two in Chrome. I would like to make Safari clip the images the same way Chrome does. I am not interested in solutions that relies on using `background-image:url(some.url.png)` if something like that exists. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

```css
img{
  position:relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  clip-path: url(#clipping);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipping);
  -webkit-transform:translateZ(1);
}
```

```html
<svg style="background: blue; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipping" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M0.501,0.971c-0.014,0-0.027-0.003-0.04-0.011l-0.34-0.194c-0.024-0.014-0.04-0.041-0.04-0.069L0.081,0.306
 c0-0.028,0.015-0.055,0.04-0.069L0.458,0.04c0.013-0.007,0.026-0.011,0.04-0.011s0.027,0.003,0.04,0.011l0.339,0.194
 c0.025,0.014,0.041,0.041,0.041,0.069l0.001,0.391c0,0.028-0.015,0.055-0.04,0.069L0.542,0.96C0.529,0.968,0.515,0.971,0.501,0.971z
 "/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div style="background-color:green; height:100px;">
<img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/140.jpg">  
</div>

<div style="background-color:blue; height:100px;">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/139.jpg">
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/Johnonym/pen/jyjzgQ

Comment: regarding the multiple compatibility issues, I would advise to not use `clip-path`. http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Comment: Thank you for your link. Do you happen know an alternative way of doing it? I am only doing a square with rounded corners as a clipping-path for my project. I was thinking about enveloping images in a container div, setting the overflow to hidden, and try to transform the image around to display only a certain part of it. I have not tried it though.

Comment: I tried a different approach, as the one mentioned in my comment above, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` for parent div of img.

`-webkit-transform:translateZ(1)` Didn't work me too.